# Laravel 5.3 file manager unable to upload image in CK editor

Tags: php, laravel-5, ckeditor, clusterpoint

I am try to integrate [CK editor](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor) in my laravel 5.3 project. It is working fine. But when I integrate [file manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager)  with it the 'Browse Server' is there but when I click there in the pop up the home page is showing.

[image: Picture of CK editor file browse]

After spend some time I found this is the problem of auth in laravel. The 'Auth' didn't allow the URL.

In my project I am using [Clusterpoint](https://www.clusterpoint.com/) as the DB. It is a remote database. I am not using the auth function in my project and for this I think I am facing this problem. Any body can have any solution for how to overcome from this problem?

The code which I have the problem,

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" name="editor" id="my-editor"></textarea>
            <script>
              CKEDITOR.replace( 'my-editor', {
                filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Images',
                filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token={{csrf_token()}}',
                filebrowserBrowseUrl: '/laravel-filemanager?type=Files',
                filebrowserUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Files&_token={{csrf_token()}}'
              });
            </script>
```

Comment: Please be more detail and give us the code that you having trouble with

Comment: Update the code. These urls are not opening....

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need auth to use laravel-filemanager, simply remove `auth` from `middlewares` in `config/lfm.php`.